# Symfony2, How can I pass parameters sort and direction using KnpPaginatorBundle and QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using KnpPaginatorBundle and I'm using QueryBuilder in Repository to select data. I'd like to know how can I pass parameters **sort** and **direction** sent by Form in the query.

**This is th form:**

```
<form action="" method="get" class="form_sort" id="myForm">
                        <span class="manage_title">Sort by:</span>
                            <select class="select_styled white_select" id="sort_list" name="option">
                                <option value="">-------</option>
        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country A-Z', 'country', {'sort': 'country', 'direction': 'asc'}) }}
        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Country Z-A', 'country', {'sort': 'country', 'direction': 'desc'}) }}
        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'City A-Z', 'destination', {'sort': 'destination', 'direction': 'asc'}) }}
        {{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'City Z-A', 'destination', {'sort': 'destination', 'direction': 'desc'}) }}
                            </select>
</form>
```

**Action Controller:**

```
public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');


$listTravels = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontend();

$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $listTravels,
    $this->get('request')->query->get('page', $page)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);

return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
    'pagination' => $pagination
));
}
```

**TravelReopsitory:**

```
public function getListTravelsFrontend()
{

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->leftJoin('t.image', 'i')
    ->addSelect('i')
    ->leftJoin('t.agence', 'a')
    ->addSelect('a')
    ->Where('t.enabled = 1');

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with direction?

Comment: direction asc or desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is handle on database layery (using mysql `ORDER BY`) so you can't pass array of data from `getResult()`. You would have to pass `QueryBuilder` instance as a target to you `paginate()` call. KnpPaginator have special Listener and Walker that can modify your query  with correct `ORDER BY` based on request and then eqecute an paginate it for you.

**TravelReopsitory:**

```
public function getListTravelsFrontendQueryBuilder()
{
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
       ->leftJoin('t.image', 'i')
       ->addSelect('i')
       ->leftJoin('t.agence', 'a')
       ->addSelect('a')
       ->Where('t.enabled = 1');

return $qb;
}
```

**Action Controller:**

```
public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');

$qb = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Travel')->getListTravelsFrontendQueryBuilder();

$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $qb,
    $request->query->get('page', $page)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);

return $this->render('ProjectFrontendBundle:Frontend:list.html.twig',array(
    'pagination' => $pagination
));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get an url without alias (t.country) like this `/travels?sort=country&direction=asc` not like this `/travels?sort=t.country&direction=asc`  ?

Comment: @hous I don't think this is possible out of the box.

Comment: @hous This feature has been requested here: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/196