# sorting with KnpPaginator

Tags: symfony, sorting, knppaginator

I have an issue trying to make my sorting with KnpPaginator works. I followed many links and try a lot of iteration in my code, it can't seem to work properly. i'm missing something but can't locate it
The only thing that works at the moment si the table headers where i can click on it but nothing happens except refreshing the page and refreshing me back on pagination 1.
I'm working on symfony 2.3

Here is my bundle configuration

```
knp_paginator:
page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
default_options:
    page_name: page                # page query parameter name
    sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
    sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
    distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
template:
    pagination: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig'     # sliding pagination controls template
    sortable: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template
```

Here is my controller where I actually setted up Knp with the getRepository

```
private function resultsAction(Request $request, User $user, $type, $archive)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive);

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $results = $paginator->paginate(
        $query,
        $request->query->getInt('page',1),
        $request->query->getInt('limit',50)
    );

    return array("results" => $results, "archive" => $archive);
}

public function offreAction(Request $request, User $user, $archive = false)
    {
        return $this->resultsAction($request, $user, Operation::OFFRE_COMMERCIALE, $archive);
    }
```

here is my repo where the query is done:

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder("opn")
            ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
            ->setParameter("type", $type)
            ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
            ->setParameter("reseller", $user->getId())
            ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
            ->setParameter('archive', $archive)
            ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
            ->getQuery()
        ;
    }
```

And here is my view where I try to make things work with Knp

```
  <tr>
       <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'general.vehicule.ref'|trans, 'opn.type') }}</th>
       <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'general.vehicule.vehicule'|trans, 'opn.resellerId') }}</th>
      <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'notifications.client'|trans, 'opn.??') }}</th>
      <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'general.date'|trans, 'opn.??') }}</th>
      <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'commerce.achat.encours.etat'|trans, 'opn.??') }}</th>
  </tr>
```

And in my table, when I click on  it refresh the page but doesn't sort it. I'm having a hard time understand how to make that work?

The place where I putted `'opn.??'` its because I don't know what to put at that particular place, I don't seem to understand the query

I would like the last dated item to be first, but being able to sort it with Knp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay i succeeded in making that work, here is what I've done.

config.yml

```
knp_paginator:
page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
default_options:
    page_name: page                # page query parameter name
    sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
    sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
    distinct: false                # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
template:
    pagination: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig'     # sliding pagination controls template
    sortable: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template
```

repo

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder("opn")
            ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
            ->setParameter("type", $type)
            ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
            ->setParameter("reseller", $user->getId())
            ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
            ->setParameter('archive', $archive)
            ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
            ->getQuery()
        ;
    }
```

controller

```
private function resultsAction(Request $request, User $user, $type, $archive)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $qb = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive);

        $results = $paginator->paginate(
            $qb,
            $request->query->get('page',1),
            $request->query->get('limit',50),
            [
                'defaultSortFieldName'      => 'opn.dateCreation',
                'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc'
            ]
        );

        return array("results" => $results, "archive" => $archive);
    }
```

and twig

```
    <tr>
          <th{% if results.isSorted('opn.id') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'general.vehicule.ref'|trans, 'opn.id') }}</th>
          <th{% if results.isSorted('opn.vehiculeMarque') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'general.vehicule.vehicule'|trans, 'opn.vehiculeMarque') }}</th>
          {% if typeOffre is defined and typeOffre == 'devisWeb' %}<th>Financement</th>{% endif %}
          <th{% if results.isSorted('opn.clientNom') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'notifications.client'|trans, 'opn.clientNom') }}</th>
          <th{% if results.isSorted('opn.dateCreation') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(results, 'general.date'|trans, 'opn.dateCreation') }}</th>
          <th>{{ 'commerce.achat.encours.etat'|trans }}</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled">{{ 'commerce.achat.action'|trans }}</th>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">{{ 'commerce.vente.operation.basculer'|trans }}</th>
 </tr>
```

and so that works

Answer (score 2):

remove `->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")`. KnpPaginator have special Listener and Walker that can modify your query with correct ORDER BY based on request and then eqecute an paginate it for you.

Config sortable look at [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#configuration-example).
Translation look at [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle#translation-in-view).

Comment: Thank you for your clarity. I found how to make the translation work with your links. However deleting `->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")` doesn't make that work

Comment: put your configuration of bundle here  and look this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193249/symfony2-how-can-i-pass-parameters-sort-and-direction-using-knppaginatorbundle hope help you

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think i have a different problem from this post. Sorry can't really understand what to do so far, I will try to make a new post.

Comment: I putted the bundle configuration in my original post/ i searched your posts and other posts, still I can't make it seem to make it work @T. Abdelmalek